# sychronized block in GAE

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

I have an app running in GAE. There are 2 cron servlets triggered by time once every few minutes. Both retrieve and update the same storage record. So I added Synchronized block to enclose almost the whole processing logic at both servlets. However, according to the time in the log, their flow is still intermixed together when they are in different JVM. looks like Synchronized block only protect it when they are in the same JVM. Am I right? If so, how to do concurrent processing in GAE? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct - synchronized blocks work only in a single process.  AppEngine cron servlets execute concurrently on any number of servers in a cloud.  You should redesign the mutual exclusion in your cron jobs to use [Datastore Transactions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/transactions).  Because such cron tasks might result in long running operations it is often useful to manage the heavy processing with [Task Queues](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/taskqueue/).

Comment: OIC, thanks. So I have to use a single task queue for my 2 servlets. If i use 2 queues, it would end up with the same issue. Correct?

Comment: No, the number of queues is not a factor.  Datastore Transactions use the more scalable Optimistic Concurrency instead of Pessimistic. That has a different issue, namely if multiple background processes attempt to modify the same data concurrently, the first process will succeed and the second process will fail (Datastore throws an exception).  Your cron task will need a loop to catch the ConcurrentModificationException, have a little sleep, and retry.